# How to load an OFM-based PFB font with fontspec?

Tags: luatex, fontspec, arabic

In my [ḍād package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/dad) (for Arabic typesetting, see also the [TUGboat paper](https://www.tug.org/members/TUGboat/tb35-3/tb111haralambous.pdf)) I use a PostScript font with OFM metrics file. I load the font in the usual way, going through an FD file. This works only for luaLaTeX, since the latter is the only OFM-compatible TeX offspring (thanks to its Omega genes).

My ḍād font is not loaded anymore when I include the fontspec package. As you can see if you visit [this overleaf page](https://www.overleaf.com/2832243jnwhcc#/7631244/), as soon as the fontspec package is loaded, the OFM-PFB font dad cannot be found anymore. This means that a user of ḍād cannot use TrueType fonts in luaLaTeX (at least not going through fontspec, which is the most practical way), and this is quite a pity.

Does someone know how to load a PFB font with OFM metrics in a fontspec-compatible way?

Answer (score 4):

Hmm not really the user interface you want, but perhaps a pointer to a solution, the document runs without error (and I hope makes the right thing, although I can't read it:( if you force the font to be loaded before `fontspec` triggers (I assume) `luaotfload` which changes the font loading

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{dad}

\setbox0\hbox{\Huge\arab{AlkitAbu AlkabYru}}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2]{Scheherazade}
\newcommand{\textarabic}[1]{\bgroup\luatextextdir TRT\arabicfont #1\egroup}




\begin{document}

\Huge\arab{AlkitAbu AlkabYru}

\Huge\arab{الكتابُ الكبيرُ}

\Huge\textarabic{الكتابُ الكبيرُ}

\end{document}
```

Comment: dear David, great to hear from you and thanks for your tip! It works indeed, but I would really be in favor of a solution that does not require a specific loading order. Is there really no way to load an OFM-PFB font after luaotfload has been read by LuaTeX?

Comment: Hi @yannis yes, been a long time! I was just looking... `texdoc luaotfload` implies ofm fonts should be loaded so my theory is that changing `dad` in the fd file to `[dad]` or `[file:dad.ofm]` or `"file:/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/ofm/public/dad/dad"` ought to work, but none of them do.... might be worth raising with the luaotfload maintainers

Comment: this sounds more like what I need! But who are the luaotfload maintainers?

Comment: @yannis they are listed here or (more usefully) a link to github where you could leave an issue I guess https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luaotfload?lang=en

Comment: @yannis moved this to github https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/273