# Which TeX engines support OFM fonts?

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, e-tex, font-metrics

I'm extremely unhappy with the limitation of tfm fonts of 15 heights / 15 depths / 63 italic corrections.
This is why I'm looking for a TeX engine which can load ofm fonts, probably etex, xetex or luatex (preferably which pass TRIP test, to be more compatible).

Following is a minimal example.

```
$ echo '(MAPFONT D 0 (FONTNAME cmr10))' > myfont.vpl
$ tftopl cmr10.tfm >> myfont.vpl
```

*This is necessary because vptovf automatically adds MAP to font 0, whereas ovp2ovf does not do this:*

```
$ vptovf myfont.vpl
```

*This is necessary, because otherwise the mentioned limitation will persist:*

```
$ echo '(OFMLEVEL H 0)' > myfont.ovp
```

```
$ vftovp myfont.vf >> myfont.ovp
$ ovp2ovf myfont.ovp
```

At this point we get myfont.ofm (considering the fact that ofm is an extension of tfm). This is an example of usage:

```
\font\myfont=myfont
\myfont
hello
\bye
```

Comment: see this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249462/how-to-load-an-ofm-based-pfb-font-with-fontspec

Comment: just luatex I'd guess but why ofm these days?

Comment: Omega and Aleph, the former having been dismissed from TeX Live since 2009. But LuaTeX should be able to understand OFM fonts. Not XeTeX.

Comment: @touhami Yes, I know about this topic. I could not get this example to work.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Let's just suppose that they are needed. Do you have any ideas why my example with luatex does not work?

Comment: @IgorLiferenko no, I had a quick experiment but no useful information to give (other than that I get no visible output either)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Is it worth opening an issue as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249462/how-to-load-an-ofm-based-pfb-font-with-fontspec? Does there exist any other place where someone can help?

Comment: luatex list (with the plain tex example)